# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "Acc"

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

**Hi , my app when runs on HWY320-U (Huawei) throws exception.


What may be reason of this?**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "Acc"
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at afa.a(SourceFile:102)
at aer.a(SourceFile:174)
at aer.a(SourceFile:151)
at afw.run(SourceFile:14)
at afy.run(SourceFile:30)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: i think it might device issue so handle your code with try-catch block.

Comment: Ya Haresh is correct. If you try to run same app on emulator, you will face same issue. Actually you need to handle that exception in throw block or try...catch

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the stacktrace, I would say that you use `Integer.parseInt()` somewhere and the input seems to be "Acc". This input cannot be parsed to an `Integer` as it is a `String`